# Polyhedron Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given a Polyhedron formed by linear constraints $$(a^Tx <= b)$$

and you have given a orthogonal basis.

Then every point inside the Polyhedron can be expressed by a linear combination of elements of the basis.

When you set the linear factor of one basis element to a fixed value,

the remaining free elements of the basis form a hyperplane.

How can you decide if the hyperplane intersects the Polyhedron?

(How do you find the linear factors so the you can express a feasible point inside the polyhedron)

**Edit:**
i hope it is now clearer

Comment: Either you need to clarify your question, or the answer is when the linear factor takes that basis element beyond a supporting hyperplane to the polytope.

Comment: The Question is how do you know if there are remaining linear factors which can take you behind the supporting hyperplane